# MySQL left join to get all matches

Tags: mysql, sql

Student might have more than parent so how can i get all parent`s mobile numbers and emails to be separated by comma?

```
SELECT Students.ID
     , Student_Name
     , Address
     , longitude
     , latitude
     , Image
     , MPOS_ID
     , Parent_EMail
     , Parent.Parent_Mobile 
  FROM Students 
  left 
  join Parent 
    on Parent.Student_ID = Students.ID 
 WHERE Students.Status = 'Active' 
   AND Students.Deleted_At is null
```

Comment: You might take a look at GROUP_CONCAT(), but if it was me, I'd resolve that part of the problem in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and `GROUP BY` to achieve this result.

`GROUP_CONCAT` will concatenate all of the values in the specified column, so you need to group by the student ID so that you don't just get a list details for every parent.

```
SELECT Students.ID, Student_Name, Address, longitude, latitude,
    Image, MPOS_ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Parent_EMail SEPARATOR ', ') as parent_emails,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Parent_Mobile SEPARATOR ', ') as parent_mobiles
FROM Students 
LEFT JOIN Parent 
    ON Parent.Student_ID = Students.ID 
WHERE Students.Status = 'Active' 
    AND Students.Deleted_At IS NULL
GROUP BY Students.ID;
```

Comment: @MohamedGamgoum No it doesn't.

Comment: @MohamedGamgoum Make sure you add the `GROUP BY` at the end of the snippet.